# Where are Xen guest config files stored?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen, administration

I'm new to Xen stuff. I have a XenServer 6.5 running, with XenCenter and a Debian installed as a PV VM. I'm trying to setup the extra security now so I don't have to learn about it after I've been screwed over. (driver domains, pvgrub, and maybe FLASK)

A lot of pages seem to talk about editing values that look like they belong inside a guest (domu) configuration file.

Where is this file located? (I looked in /etc/xen)
What are some common file formats?  (so I can use find at least)
Does the location differ if I go with something like Debian as dom0?

Comment: I can't really call this much of an answer because I've since deleted the hard drive I had this set up on and can't really give very exact information. The config files the web pages are talking about editing are if you are using xl or xm, xe (xapi) does not use config file to launch vms. Xapi seems to store the information in templates that you can modify, export, and import. It may be stored somehow in the xenstore.. I don't really understand the what the xenstore handles though.. I did find a file ending in .db (state.db I think) that was modified when VMs were altered.

Answer (score 2):

The complete configuration is stored as XML in

> /var/xapi/state.db

It's recommended to use only the xapi commands to edit the configuration. There is also a dbtool from citrix here http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX121564.

I think the way the information is stored is specific to xenserver, howerver someone needs to confirm this.